# Randomly divide a pandas dataframe into groups at once for x-fold crossvalidation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

Let's say I have a dataframe with 500 rows. I want to perform 10-fold cross validation. So, I need to divide this data into 10 sets each containing 50 rows. I want to perform this division of whole data into 10 groups at once that too *randomly*.

Is there a way to do so using any library like pandas, numpy, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

You could use sklearn's [KFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 

# create dummy dataframe with 500 rows
features = np.random.randint(1, 100, 500)
labels = np.random.randint(1, 100, 500)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"X": features, "Y": labels})

kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=True) # Define the split - into 10 folds 
kf.get_n_splits(df) # returns the number of splitting iterations in the cross-validator
print(kf) 

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(df):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index) 
    print("TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = df.loc[train_index, "X"], df.loc[test_index, "X"]
    y_train, y_test = df.loc[train_index, "Y"], df.loc[test_index, "Y"]
```

Example [taken from here](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6).

Comment: I actually should have edited the question. I didn't want to use KFold actually at all. I wanted to get a logic which would randomly divide the data into 10 groups at once. Such a method is not available I guess in any of the module. I made my own logic. However, if there is some optimised solution I would be grateful.

Comment: @A.Sinha Thanks for the update. I suggest you post this as a new question and either close this question or accept my answer so that others can see that the matter is solved. In any case – good luck with your project!